# How to check for row lock contention while updating something in the same table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, transactions, locking

How can I make sure that my update queries do not wait for a commit when the same row is locked by another transaction that has not yet committed?

I tried using a trigger before update on a column and wanted to check for contention for the row but since the trigger is itself not executed if there is a contention on the same row, i had to drop that option. This is how I designed the trigger and wished to check inside begin for row contention

```
create or replace trigger trig_row_contention_sig 
before update of most_used on tbl_sig for each row
```

But the trigger is also getting queued. Is there any other way? I would also be happy if I can discard those update queries post issuing and checking for contention for the same rows THAN wait.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774646/in-oracle-a-way-for-updates-to-not-lock-rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a pessimistic locking strategy. This attempts to acquire the lock before issuing the commit:

```
 declare
     cursor c1 is
         select * from your_table
         where id = 1
         for update of whatever -- this is the pessimistic lock
         nowait -- abandon the attempt if row is already locked
         ;
     r1 c1%rowtype;
begin
    open c1;
    fetch c1 into r1;
    update your_table 
    set whatever = whatever + 1
    where current of c1;
    close c1;
    commit; -- release the lock
end;
```

This toy code has NOWAIT, so the query fails if the row is already locked. We can also WAIT for a specified timeout or wait indefinitely (what you're doing now).

Another neat feature of the SELECT ... FOR UPDATE syntax is SKIP LOCKED, which allows us to implement queuing. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2126016).

---

> "Why does the trigger not work ? I mean when i have set it up to run before update, shouldnt it also be executed before row locking."

That's not what `before update` means. All triggers are effectively `ON <<event>>`. Triggers fire when the event happens. The trigger can't fire until the row is actually updated.

The `before` and `after` triggers refer to the **state** of the row. In a `before update` trigger we can reference :OLD values and manipulate :NEW values. In an `after update` trigger we can reference :OLD values and :NEW values but cannot change :NEW values.

Comment: hmmm, SKIP LOCKED. Never heard of it but I can think of times when that might have been useful.

Comment: @BriteSponge - it was undocumented (and hence unsupported) prior to 11g. But it's legit now.

Comment: @APC Hi, hi have used the pessimistic lock strategy and it seems to suffice. Just out of curiosity !!. Why does the trigger not work ? I mean when i have set it up to run before update, shouldnt it also be executed before row locking.

Comment: Triggers fire when the event happens. The trigger can't fire until the row is updated

Comment: @APC yes but that is not what I have mentioned it to work like, I have used 'before update on' to place it before any updates.